# how to re-index (number) sorted sqlite table

Tags: sql, sqlite

for example I've got nodes with indexes

```
1
2
7
8
```

I need to change indexes to

```
1 
2 
3 
4
```

I can

```
UPDATE TODO SET id = id + 1000000000
UPDATE TODO SET id = id - (1000000000 + 1)
```

(tricky because id must be unique)

to shift all the indexes and make 0 1 6 7 but I need to make relation, need to make first index shift to 0, and other index shift to previous index. There is no stored procedures in sqlite so I'm confised about How can I make such relation without variables?

every logics tips are welcome.

Comment: why do you need to reindex?  Surely the only thing that matters is that they are unique, not what their actual values are?

Comment: For adittional clarity as feature, 1 2 3 4 is more readable then 1 2 3 7. Sure, there is case to just display 1 2 3 4 all the time but I want to keep numbers on indexes that user can remember and reindex only when he wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
 UPDATE todo SET id = rowid
```

Comment: awesome ) but before it I still need UPDATE TODO SET id = id + 1000000000 as @CL mentored

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a new, empty table with the same structure, but make `id` an autoincrement column (declare it as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`);
2. copy all records into that table, in the desired order, but without the `id` column:

   ```
   INSERT INTO NewTable(all_the, other, columns)
   SELECT all_the, other, columns
   FROM OldTable
   ORDER BY id;
   ```
3. drop the old table, and [rename](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) the new one to the old name.

(This will create `id`s starting at 1.)

Comment: This is the best and most universal method to do it! Explaining it step-by-step with and generic example.