# Re-ordering AutoIncrement primary key in sqllite

Tags: android, sqlite, primary-key, auto-increment

I'm developing an android app which uses an sqlite database. For every record(row), I'm using an autoincrement field as primary key. What my actual problem is, i need to automatically re-order all the record's primary key after deleting a record in between.
For example, say i have 5 records which start from 1 then 2,3,4,5..suppose if i had deleted the 3rd record with primary key value 3, it should automatically reorder the primarykey numbers so that it should appear as 1,2,3,4 ...

Any method for this? Please help!

thank you

Comment: why do you want it ? Leave sqlite manage the primary keys in its way

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to re-index (number) sorted sqlite table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644577/how-to-re-index-number-sorted-sqlite-table)

Comment: Primary keys do not change their value. Why do you need to renumber them?

Answer (score 0):

There is no method for this. If you want behaviour like this, you'll have to manually do it after every delete either by re-adding your whole database or keeping a record of the 'freed up Ids' which you fill up with any next insert.